# Finding global extreme values of a function

Tags: calculus

I have this function $f(x,y)=5x^3-7y$ with $0\le x, y\le 1$.
Find the values of the global min and max
So, I got partial derivatives $f_x'(x,y)=15x^2$, and $f'_y=-7$.
But then I run into confusion on how to proceed.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen above, $f_y$ is never zero, and the extrema must therefore lie on the boundary. Let's try to find the max and min on all four boundary curves:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}_1 = [0,1] \times \{1\}&:-7 \le f(x, 1) = 5x^3 - 7 \le -2 \\ \mathcal{C}_2 = \{0\} \times [0,1]&:   -7 \le f(0,y) = -7 \le -7y \le 0 \\ \mathcal{C}_3 = [0,1] \times \{0\}&:  ~~~0 \le f(x,0) =5x^3 \le 5\\
\mathcal{C}_4 = \{1\} \times [0,1]&:   -2 \le f(1,y) = 5 -7y  \le 5 \\
\end{align}

Conequently, the global maximum is $5$ at $(1,0)$, and the global minimum is $-7$ at $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the global Minimum is given by $-7$ and the Maximum by $5
$

Comment: The domain is the non-negative unit square, the max cannot be $\infty$.

Comment: i have lost that $0\le y\le 1$